# EntityFramework .Take() Losing Performance Over Time

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, linq, entity-framework

I have written a function that allows me to run a function against entities a specific number at a time, dynamically adjusting for the query time. However, as it continues through the entities, the time per query gets progressively longer even when taking only 1 entity.

```
public async Task Work(Expression<Func<dbase, bool>> predicate, Action<CollectionsMax, dbase> action)
{
    try
    {
        using (var cmax = _cmax)
        {
            cmax.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            double count = await cmax.dbases.CountAsync(predicate);
            var takeAmount = 1;
            var taken = 0;

            var takeTimer = new Stopwatch();
            while (taken != (int) count)
            {
                cmax.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                takeTimer.Reset();

                takeTimer.Start();
                IQueryable<dbase> query = cmax.dbases.Where(predicate)
                    .OrderBy(o => o.id)
                    .Skip(taken)
                    .Take(Math.Min(takeAmount, (int) count - taken));

                var take = await query.ToListAsync();

                takeTimer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Took {0} and that took {1}ms", take.Count, takeTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                taken += take.Count;
                if (takeTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 2000)
                {
                    takeAmount = takeAmount + 5;
                }
                if (takeTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 2000)
                {
                    takeAmount = takeAmount - 5;
                }
                if (takeAmount < 1)
                    takeAmount = 1;

                Parallel.ForEach(take, obj => action(_max, obj));

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Output: http://puu.sh/hxMSD/68dbf4f079.png

Comment: Please show us the SQL involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following part:

```
IQueryable<dbase> query = cmax.dbases.Where(predicate)
    .OrderBy(o => o.id)
    .Skip(taken)
    .Take(Math.Min(takeAmount, (int) count - taken));
```

When `taken != 0`, the server needs to execute the query, then run through the whole list and discard the first `taken` rows. The problem is not linq, but rather the sql engine, because it cannot take advantage of indexes. The problem is not `Take`, but rather `Skip`. [Joel On Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) has a more general explanation of the problem using the C `strlen` function.

Usually only the first few pages are read so it is not a problem. But if more pages need to be read, then the problem gets worse. This is why systems that need to fetch later pages do not use `Skip`, but rather use ordering and filtering. In your case, given that you are ordering by id, you can say:

```
IQueryable<dbase> query = cmax.dbases.Where(predicate)
    .OrderBy(o => o.id)
    .Where(o => i.id > LastTakenId)
    .Take(Math.Min(takeAmount, (int) count - taken));


    ...
    LastTakenId = take.Max(o => o.id);
```

PS: you can also speed things up slightly if you use the following `Take` overload:

```
int toTake = Math.Min(takeAmount, (int) count - taken);
IQueryable<dbase> query = cmax.dbases.Where(predicate)
    .OrderBy(o => o.id)
    .Where(o => i.id > LastTakenId)
    .Take(() => toTake);
```

because this allows the EF engine to cache the generated sql and then just replace the new take number. See section 4.2 [of the performance considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#4).

Answer (score 4):

In this portion of the code:

```
IQueryable<dbase> query = cmax.dbases.Where(predicate)
  .OrderBy(o => o.id)
  .Skip(taken)
  .Take(Math.Min(takeAmount, (int) count - taken));
```

Skip isn't free. It doesn't remember that the previous time you evaluated this query you already processed the previous entities.

So a better way to think about it is your output is:

```
Read 1 and that took 457ms
Read 7, skipping the first 1 and that took 172ms
Read 18, skipping the first 7 and that took 266ms
Read 34, skipping the first 18 and that took 378ms
etc..
```

Then it makes more sense why it takes progressively longer.

Comment: Is there a method to only take a range?  Such as how LIMIT works with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

The more entities you load from the database, the more entities your context is keeping track of, which also slows everything down.